Pagination structure breaks when clicked on certain number of pages in React
In a React project, Posts data with 500 records is extracted from a certain API. Pagination is created with a limit of 10 records per page. Since, it has large number of pages, page numbers are truncated with 'dots' to denote the page availbility. An input box makes direct page search possible, but, when searched the page all page numbers are displayed at once.
See below for illustration

As you can see from image, pagination component becomes wierd when tried to search page number, it happens when searched after page 5.
Pagination logic implemented with following logic
const numberOfPages = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
    numberOfPages.push(i);
  }

  // Current active button number
  const [currentButton, setCurrentButton] = useState(1);

  // Array of buttons what we see on the page
  const [arrOfCurrButtons, setArrOfCurrButtons] = useState([]);

  const [searchPage, setSearchPage] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let tempNumberOfPages = [...arrOfCurrButtons];

    let dotsInitial = "...";
    let dotsLeft = "... ";
    let dotsRight = " ...";

    if (numberOfPages.length < 6) {
      tempNumberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    } else if (currentButton >= 1 && currentButton <= 3) {
      tempNumberOfPages = [1, 2, 3, 4, dotsInitial, numberOfPages.length];
    } else if (currentButton === 4) {
      const sliced = numberOfPages.slice(0, 5);
      tempNumberOfPages = [...sliced, dotsInitial, numberOfPages.length];
    } else if (currentButton > 4 && currentButton < numberOfPages.length - 2) {
      const sliced1 = numberOfPages.slice(currentButton - 2, currentButton); 
      const sliced2 = numberOfPages.slice(currentButton, currentButton + 1);
      tempNumberOfPages = [
        1,
        dotsLeft,
        ...sliced1,
        ...sliced2,
        dotsRight,
        numberOfPages.length,
      ];
    } else if (currentButton > numberOfPages.length - 3) {
      const sliced = numberOfPages.slice(numberOfPages.length - 4);
      tempNumberOfPages = [1, dotsLeft, ...sliced];
    } else if (currentButton === dotsInitial) {
      setCurrentButton(arrOfCurrButtons[arrOfCurrButtons.length - 3] + 1);
    } else if (currentButton === dotsRight) {
      setCurrentButton(arrOfCurrButtons[3] + 2);
    } else if (currentButton === dotsLeft) {
      setCurrentButton(arrOfCurrButtons[3] - 2);
    }

    setArrOfCurrButtons(tempNumberOfPages);
    setCurrentPage(currentButton);
  }, [currentButton]);

And now below is the Search component required for searching pages
      <button onClick={() => onHandleShowInput()}>
        Page {currentButton} of {numberOfPages.length}
      </button>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input type="number" value={searchPage} placeholder="Search Pages" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>

Please mention some optimal solution or suggestions highly appreciated.
Look out for codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-dijkstra-mxtsqw
